# How to give name to the functions of a library header in C

Tags: c

I am trying to write a generic library in pure c , just some data structures like stack, queue...

In my stack.h when giving name to those functions. I have questions about that.

1. Can I use such name, for example "init" as the function name to init a stack. Will there be something wrong?
2. I know maybe there exist other functions which just do other things and have the same name as "init". Then would the program be confused, especially when i both include the different init's headers.

3.I know my worry may be unnecessary, but i still want to know the principle.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: C does not have namespaces, so there can only be one single init() function in any given compiled program's function list. The usual workaround is to put a prefix on your function names so they don't conflict. "apporc_init()" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. init() might be okay (if you're including your library into something else as an actual library, rather than compiling its source in), but it's better practice to use something like stack_init(), and to prefix your library's functions with stack_ or queue_, etc.
2. A program using your library may get confused, depending on the order the libraries are included, see #1.

As far as the principles go, the linker (on Linux, anyway) will look for symbols, and there's an ordering to how those symbols will be found. For more information, you can check out the man page for dlsym(), and specifically for RTLD_NEXT.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use such name, for example "init" as the function name to init a
>   stack. Will there be something wrong?

Yes, if anyone else wants a function named `init`.

> I know my worry may be unnecessary, but i still want to know the
>   principle

Your worry is necessary, this (the lack of namespaces) is a serious problem in C.

- Export as few functions as possible. Make everything `static` if you can
- Prefix function names with something. For instance, instead of `init`, try `stack_init`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have namespaces in C so usually you prefix every identifier with the name or nickname of your library.

```
init();
```

becomes

```
fancy_lib_init();
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be existing libraries doing what you want (e.g. [Glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib)). At least, study them a little before writing your own.

If you claim to develop a generic reusable C library, I suggest having naming conventions. For instance, have all the identifiers (notably function names, typedef-s, struct names...) share some common prefix.

Be systematic in your naming conventions. For instance, initializers for stacks and for queues should have similar names & signatures, and end with `_init`. Document your naming conventions.

Define very clearly how should data be allocated and released. Who and when should call free?

Comment: Yeah, i am studying those data structures and write that for praticing, not really for use.
Thank you for you advice.

Comment: Then studying existing free software source code should be a good idea, you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Even better, you could consider contributing some new code to such free software libraries! To do that, you'll need to study some algorithms which are not implemented yet in these libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Function names in C are global. If two functions in a program have the same name, the program should fail to compile. (Well, sometimes it fails at link time, but the idea still holds.)

Generally, you get around this problem by using some sort of prefix or suffix on the function names in your library. "apporc_stack_init()" is much less likely to collide with something than "init()" is.

Comment: *Non-static* function names in C are global.

Comment: True enough, but functions that he wants his clients to call aren't going to be static, are they?

Comment: Yes, I just thought it might be a useful improvement to your answer.